# Apache's ssl mode while using SSL Termination setup with Haproxy?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, haproxy

Do we have to disable Apache's ssl mode using the command `a2dismod ssl` for using the mentioned setup as while starting haproxy, it is complaining about port `443 is already being used`?

Comment: Why would you run both apache and haproxy on the same server? Do you need to balance inbound connections to a single/local-hosted backend?!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, then you have a server that runs apache and haproxy. And now apache reports the `already being used` error? So this means that both try to use the 433 port.

So yes, you can (and need to) disable the ssl module and/or deactivate the `listen XXX:443` configuration line.

Comment: This, or move apache https port to something else (444?), in your ports.conf and virtualhosts. Make sure haproxy adds the X-Forwarded-Proto header/could be required by your balanced app.

Answer (score 0):

[Syn](https://superuser.com/users/663173/syn) has the right answer. As illustrated in this post [Run Apache, Nginx & HAProxy on Same Server (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS)](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/run-apache-nginx-haproxy-on-same-server-debian-ubuntu-centos).

The idea is for your apache server to listen locally so the ports are open for haproxy to listen publically.

(slightly modified, since we're just dealing w haproxy and apache here)

> edit the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file.
>
> Change
>
> `Listen 80`
> `Listen 443`
>
> To
>
> `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`
> `Listen 127.0.0.1:443`

then also your site config in sites-available

> `<VirtualHost *:80>`
>
> To
>
> `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`
>
> If there are SSL virtual host, then also change
>
> `<VirtualHost *:443>`
>
> To
>
> `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>`
>
> Restart Apache.

now configure haproxy (from fresh install)

> `nano /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

> Add the following code snippet at the end of the file

```
frontend http
    bind publicipaddress:80
    mode http
    redirect scheme https code 301

frontend https
    bind publicipaddress:443
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

backend apache
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server apache 127.0.0.1:443 check
```